# laravel throws error when returning ->first() in controller

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

this:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        return DB::table('apps')->where('id', $id)->first();//->get();
    }
```

will return an error: 
`UnexpectedValueException in Response.php line 399:
The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given.`

this will not return an error (but I cant use it since I need an object not array):

```
public function show($id)
    {
        return DB::table('apps')->where('id', $id)->get();
    }
```

whats wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a model set up for 'apps'? You should create a model then use `AppModel::find($id)`

Comment: have you tried this
return DB::table('apps')->where('id', $id)->first;

Comment: @owaishanif786 That won't work, `first` is a method, not a property and the DB won't attempt to call it magically. The issue here is the DB facade returns a raw PHP object and Laravel expects either a string, array/collection, response object or eloquent model to be returned from a controller, not a raw object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DB` facade will return a raw PHP object. When returning data from a controller in Laravel it should be a string, array, eloquent model, or response object (ie, view). Since you're returning a raw object, Laravel attempts to cast it to a string, which is the source of your problem.

The best way to resolve this would be use a [Model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#defining-models) instead of the `DB` facade

```
public function show($id)
{
    return AppModel::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
}
```

<sub>Note: I'm using `firstOrFail()` here because if an app doesn't exist, Laravel will automatically abort with a 404.</sub>

By returning an eloquent model, Laravel knows to automatically cast it to JSON.

If you don't want to use eloquent, then case the object to an array.

```
public function show($id)
{
    return (array)DB::table('apps')->where('id', $id)->first();
}
```

Laravel will take that array and case it to JSON for you in the response.

Comment: I am getting the error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::firstOrFail()` BTW, I cant use AppModel because I want to do code reuse between controllers so i need something dynamic

Comment: `return DB::table('apps')->where('id', $id)->first();` will return `UnexpectedValueException in Response.php line 399:
The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given.`

Comment: @SexyMF did you try just 'first()'? Don't forget to also cast to an array.

Comment: @jfadich look at the comment above yours. `return DB::table('apps')->where('id', $id)->first();`

Comment: @fatnjazzy look at the answer. You're missing the part that actually fixes it. The response needs to be cast to an array. `return (array)DB::table('apps')->where('id', $id)->first();`

Comment: @SexyMF you are missing me the part that casts the result to an array.

Comment: @SexyMF 'I cant use AppModel because I want to do code reuse between controllers so i need something dynamic' This is a code smell to me, you may want to take another look at your design. Using a model makes code reuse easier not harder. Not using a model make you miss out on A LOT of what makes Laravel great!

Comment: Thanks! I missed it